# xml jquery ajax json polling

Tags: ajax, json

I am try get xml feed every 10 sec or  add the new xml feed to the existing displayed results . Can someone show me how i can do that using ajax and json call backs.

Also, if I want to take a step further and want to paginate it by breaking down into 5 results per pages how would I do that?

If someone could show me some working examples would be really great

My code is below.. please feel free to expand

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Jquery Xml Ajax</title>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"sample-xml-feed.xml",
           dataType:"xml",
           success:parseXml

           });                     
                           });

   function parseXml (xml) {

       $(xml).find("Tutorial").each(function() {

        $("#output").append($(this).attr("author") +"<br/>")                           

                                   });


   }

</script>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>


XML BIT  below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RecentTutorials>
  <Tutorial author="The Reddest">
    <Title>Silverlight and the Netflix API</Title>
    <Categories>
      <Category>Tutorials</Category>
      <Category>Silverlight 2.0</Category>
      <Category>Silverlight</Category>
      <Category>C#</Category>
      <Category>XAML</Category>
    </Categories>
    <Date>1/13/2009</Date>
  </Tutorial>
  <Tutorial author="The Hairiest">
    <Title>Cake PHP 4 - Saving and Validating Data</Title>
    <Categories>
      <Category>Tutorials</Category>
      <Category>CakePHP</Category>
      <Category>PHP</Category>
    </Categories>
    <Date>1/12/2009</Date>
  </Tutorial>
  <Tutorial author="The Tallest">
    <Title>Silverlight 2 - Using initParams</Title>
    <Categories>
      <Category>Tutorials</Category>
      <Category>Silverlight 2.0</Category>
      <Category>Silverlight</Category>
      <Category>C#</Category>
      <Category>HTML</Category>
    </Categories>
    <Date>1/6/2009</Date>
</Tutorial>
  <Tutorial author="The Fattest">
    <Title>Controlling iTunes with AutoHotkey</Title>
    <Categories>
      <Category>Tutorials</Category>
      <Category>AutoHotkey</Category>
    </Categories>
    <Date>12/12/2008</Date>
  </Tutorial>
</RecentTutorials>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about running your AJAX request inside a `setInterval()`?

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url:"sample-xml-feed.xml",
       dataType:"xml",
       success:parseXml
   }); 
}, 10000); // 10 seconds
```

For the pagination your `parseXml()` function should take care of the logic. Keep a counter variable somewhere and as soon as it reaches a 5th result, `append` to a new container and reset the counter.

Comment: Do u happen to have an example on how i can keep adding the next 5 items to the existing results?  thanks